# Regex How to validate not allow to dash

Tags: javascript, regex

How I validate not allow repeat two dash (--) after specific string `0-1P`:

```
^\w0-1P(?:([\w-])
```

Example:

`10-1P-8` will valid

`10-1Pabc--` will invalid (because has twodash)

`z0-1PDTD--SDSA--` will invalid (because has twodash repeat twice time)

[Link my regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/uXS3pt/1) but it valid threedash(---), how can i fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion as this one:

```
^\w0-1P(?!.*--)[\w-]*$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXS3pt/2)

`(?!.*--)` is negative lookahead that will fail the match if we have `--` anywhere after matching `\w0-1P` at the start of input.

Comment: thanks pro so much !